# How to Initialise Class Fields for Aggregation and Composition in Java?

Tags: java, aggregation, composition

If I have the following class, `Foo`, where `Bar` is also a class:

```
public class Foo {
    private Bar baz;

    public Foo() {
    }
}
```

Am I right in thinking that if I initialise `baz` where it is declared I will have an aggregate relationship between `Foo` and `Bar` and if I initialise `baz` in `Foo`'s constructor I will have a composite relationship? Like this:

**Aggregate (I think this is probably incorrect?):**

```
public class Foo {
    private Bar baz = new Bar();

    public Foo() {
    }
}
```

**Composite:**

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        baz = new Bar();
    }
}
```

I'm a little new to Java, and seeing as everything is a class, I'm having difficulty visualising how (in particular) the aggregate relationship works unless I make `baz` `static`. If I create `baz` somewhere else and pass it in to the constructor of `Foo`, then won't `baz` just be a composite of some other class? Bit confuzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading more about the [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). It's what you describe in your last sentence. Its a pattern that removes hard-coded dependencies as in both of your examples, but this job is delegated to a higher-level authority.

You would get something like:

```
public class Foo {

    private Bar baz;

    public Foo(Bar baz) {
        this.baz= baz;
    }
}
```

The actual instance of baz can be changed in both compile and runtime.

The actual **composition** means that class Bar has no meaning (or value) without the class Foo, and it cannot exist without the Foo, - Bar "is a part of" Foo. An example would be: an IMEI number is a part of the phone.

The **aggregation** tells that Foo only owns the Bar, - Bar "has" Foo. An example would be: a battery is a part of the phone. Other devices that are not phones could also have batteries.

These two concepts don't have much to do with the way you code it.

Answer (score 0):

Composition

```
final class Car{  

  private final Engine engine;  

  Car(EngineSpecs specs) {  
    engine = new Engine(specs);  
  }  

  void move() {  
    engine.work();  
  }  
}
```

Aggregation

```
final class Car {  

  private Engine engine;  

  void setEngine(Engine engine) {  
    this.engine = engine;  
  }  

  void move() {  
    if (engine != null)  
      engine.work();  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but what about my comment about `bar` being a composite *eventually* in the aggregate case?